# saving multidimensional array as rows in mysql using laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, multidimensional-array

i have a multidimensional array from a form that looks like this:

```
  $items =  array:8 [▼
  "units" => array:4 [▼
    0 => "1"
    1 => "1"
    2 => "1"
    3 => "1"
  ]
  "article_group" => array:4 [▼
    0 => "2401"
    1 => "2503"
    2 => "1360"
    3 => "1198"
  ]
  "article" => array:4 [▶]
  "description_en" => array:4 [▶]
  "unit_price" => array:4 [▶]
  "discount" => array:4 [▶]
  "invoice" => array:4 [▶]
  "delivery_note" => array:4 [▶]
]
```

The form is dynamically generated, and will not always contain 4 values, but they will always contain the same amount of values.

What i want to do is to save these records in a mysql database like this:

```
$bookingDetails = new bookingDetails;
$bookingDetails->units = units[0];
$bookingDetails->article_group = article_group[0];
$bookingDetails->article = article[0];
$bookingDetails->description_en = description_en[0];
$bookingDetails->unit_price = unit_price[0];
...
$bookingDetails->save();

and then the same thing with [1] and [2] and so on.
```

but how do i iterate through this in that way?

Regards Johan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply make a `for` or `foreach` loop as

```
for($i=0;$i<count($items['units']);$i++){
   $bookingDetails->units = $items['units'][$i];
   $bookingDetails->article_group = $items['article_group'][$i];
   $bookingDetails->article = $items['article'][$i];
   $bookingDetails->description_en = $items['description_en'][$i];
   $bookingDetails->unit_price = $items['unit_price'][$i];
   $bookingDetails->save();
}
```

Comment: yeah, that worked, not sure what i was thinking... Thanks alot!

Answer (score 2):

Rather than hitting the database **n** number of times, in your case, **count** times, you can do the same in **ONE HIT** using bulk insert.

`$your_data = array(
            array('col_name_1'=>'Value 1', 'col_name_2'=>'Value 2'),
            array('col_name_1'=>'Value 3', 'col_name_2'=>'Value 4')
        );
your_model_name::insert($your_data);`

This will improve the **response time** of your application.